# How would I return the lowest value from the list without using shortcuts?

Tags: c#, .net

I was given a list of numbers, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }. I was asked to return the lowest value without using shortcuts, e.g. `.Min()` etc.

Comment: Loop over the items and keep track of the smallest item as you loop.

Comment: Why would you not use the smallest amount of code required to solve your problem? What's wrong with using LINQ to find you the smallest element? What sort of programming are we teaching if we're telling people not to use the best tool for the job?

Comment: What kinds of code constructs qualify as "shortcuts", and which are permitted?

Comment: I removed the "Also, how would you recommend I go about perfecting my skills in c# to for these types of excersises." part to the question as it is a second question, not related to the title, and is too broad. If the OP wants that answer he should do a Google search.

Comment: The idea is to use as much code as possible, not sure why.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde I guess that would depend on the exercise. Sometimes you need to show that you understand how things work. If you can't find the smallest value in a list, _without_ using LINQ, then you can't program.

Comment: @MAV Well, if you don't know LINQ, I wouldn't hire you. Seriously, I've seen too many programmers fail because they reimplemented all this stuff due to ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in old-fashion imperative way. Works with all comparable types:

```
public static class MyEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static T Min<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (list == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
        }
        T min = default (T);
        bool initialized = false;
        foreach (T elem in list)
        {
            if (!initialized)
            {
                min = elem;
                initialized = true;
            }
            else if (min == null) // Do not compare with null, reset min
            {
                min = elem;
            }
            else if (elem != null && min.CompareTo(elem) > 0) // Compare only when elem is not null
            {
                min = elem;
            }
        }
        if (!initialized)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("list is empty");
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var min1 = list.Min();
var min2 = MyEnumerableExtensions.Min(list);
```

Also, is only `Min` method is restricted from Linq, additional tricks are possible. Works for numbers only:

```
var minViaMax = -list.Select(x => -x).Max();
var minViaAggregate = list.Aggregate(Math.Min);
```

Comment: What if `list` is empty?

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to give you the answer to your homework question for you directly, however to get you started just loop over the list and keep track of the smallest one you found. When you are done the smallest you found is the smallest in the list.

For your second part, it is just basic problem solving. Look at the problem, break it into smaller pieces. For example, for your problem you could break it in to:

- How do I loop over a list
- How do I remember a value between loops
- How do i compare if the remembered value is smaller than the current loop value
- How do I replace my remembered value if the current loop value is smaller

Then solve each piece individually.

Comment: I removed the "Also, how would you recommend I go about perfecting my skills in c# to for these types of excersises." part to the OP's question as it is a second question, not related to the title, and is too broad. If the OP wants that answer he should do a Google search.

Comment: Great break down! And  I will also go to Google to find a definition of C# content(@Enigmativity).